# ethersjs is there a function to get liquidity from a liquidity pair?

Tags: ethers.js

Im using ethers.js

I have got the pairAddress from a transaction, on Bscscan the address will show the pair of two tokens and the amount of each token for that pair.

If there anyway in ethers to get those amounts?

Thanks